# React index remains the same value (0)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to render this reactstrap CustomInput in a loop. Everything renders correctly, however, the `console.log(index)` always prints out 0. I'm not sure why?

Could someone please explain why this is happening and how I can fix it? I

```
 {managementTabData.map((item, index) => (
    <tr>
        <td>
            <CustomInput
                type="switch"
                id="exampleCustomSwitch"
                name="customSwitch"
                checked={item.allowView}
                onClick={() => console.log(index)}
            />
        </td>
    </tr>
))}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Well, I'm unable to reproduce this for similar arrangement of components. [ref](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-sinoussi-1x3ph?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: add a key to the looping item.

Comment: I looked into closures. But how would I rewrite this piece of code so that console.log(index) is already the correct value?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is due to how closures work in javascript, if you add the index as id of your component and read it by `event.target.id` then it should work.

```
{managementTabData.map((item, index) => (
    <tr>
        <td>
            <CustomInput
                type="switch"
                id={index}
                name="customSwitch"
                checked={item.allowView}
                onClick={(event) => console.log(event.target.id)}
            />
        </td>
    </tr>
))}
```

Another option is to write function and bind to this element which is not great idea.